# c#: Fluent Migrator/MigSharp/migratordotnet support version numbering with Application.ProductVersion in C# code?

Tags: c#, migration, migratordotnet, fluent-migrator

I am very interested in using one of the products to do migration but not only in the database but also the file system etc.

My initial thought was i would love to read the  Application.ProductVersion  but it returns a string but most of the migrations need a LONG or similar?

I don't know if anybody is doing this, but my idea was having 2 distinct versions of the migrate.

1 to migrate the product i.e. Change directories, or things in the file system etc where i would use the Application.ProductVersion

1. to migrate the database where i would use a version number of the database which I presume would come from a field?

Is anybody using it this way?

Any ideas which product would support something like this?

My migrations are not always database specific but sometimes application specific.

The way things work at the moment it appears that every new version would have to be a whole number i.e. 1, 2, 3 , 4 etc... and doesn't take into account minor, revisions etc..

Look forward to any insight

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MigratorDotNet doesn't require that the version numbers be consecutive (actually, their current recommendation is to use timestamps formatted as longs). So if you are e.g. sure that the major version will never contain more than two digits, the minor version will never contain more than four, and the build number and revision number will never contain more than five digits each, you could combine this into a long. For example, 2.34.1023.86 would become 0200340102300086. If your next version is 2.42.0.2 (0200420000000002), the migration engine will handle that. Although it feels like a bit of a hack (albeit one that I like), it should work to create a separate assembly with "migrations" that actually manipulate the file system etc. However, you'd possibly need a separate database to contain the SchemaInfo table that MigratorDotNet uses to keep track of the applied versions. Similar hacks could probably work with other migration products.

Comment: Hi Aasmund, thanks for the info.. The thing i don't understand is how do i pass the current version to the migration i.e.  converting the ProductVersion from 2.42.0.2 to a number like (0200420000000002) but then passing this to the framework?

Comment: I presume i need to call this migration classes before i show my main form to do any migrations / upgrades etc

Comment: With regards to the database versioning, where do i store my version for the database and pass it into the migration. My application migration would be productversion but the database version really needs to come from a field in the db which i need to update when the migration is complete... or am i missing the point :-)

Comment: @Martin: Each migration class has a `Migration` attribute, which presumably would reflect the product version at the time you created the migration. After your main method has read ProductVersion and converted it to a long, you can pass it to MigratorDotNet's `Migrator.MigrateTo()` method (or a similar method in another framework). Or you can simply use `Migrator.MigrateToLastVersion()`, without even bothering with figuring out what ProductVersion is - you simply trust that your migration DLL contains exactly those migration classes that are needed for the current version.

Comment: @Martin: I'm not quite sure what you meant by "the database version really needs to come from a field in the db", but the migration library creates a separate DB table into which it inserts one row for each migration it has applied. This table is then used to determine the current state of the database and which migrations need to be applied. Because of this behaviour, I think you don't need to mess around with the ProductVersion numbers. Just go with sequential numbering (1, 2, 3, ...) or timestamps (today at 17:03:24 would be 20110307170324).

Answer (score 0):

In MigSharp, you can also choose to used a long as a timestamp. So, Aasmund's suggestion would work with Mig# too. In version 2.1 of Mig# you will have the option of completely customizing the timestamp format (as long as you can compute a long from it).

So, if for any given moment (i.e. database version) there's a defined state of how your filesystem and database schema should look like, then you can use a migration framework and have the migration execute whatever is needed on the filesystem and/or the database. If you want to only change the filesystem in one migration, then do so. In this case, the database will then only be updated to hold the latest migration version number.